# why the performance different when I calling two times and have low complie times occupation rate?

Tags: julia

[this is three functions when first call and second call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYUCt.png)

what happen to this?
I　find the doc of julia performance tips, but in their examples are about compile time.
In this case, what is the reason if this situation?
those functions are HTTP.request post get and JSON.parse(String(r.body)).

Comment: Julia uses JIT, so this is should be unsurprising for you: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/understanding-better-jit-and-llvm-in-julia/42784

Comment: "I　find the doc of julia performance tips, but in their examples are about compile time. In this case, what is the reason if this situation?" You already found the answer (compilation time), why do you think that's not the explanation here? Also, it's not clear what you mean by "low compile times occupation rate" in the question title.

Comment: Hey Cactus, as other have mentioned, it is likely because of Julia's JIT compilation. It might also be helpful to see some code here as well.

Comment: thanks a lots.but i put @time front of that 3 function the gc time only 6.52%.
so i don't know is the compile time let it slow.